# Как правильно выделить корень в слове "песчаными"?

Tags: словообразование, корень-слова

Как правильно выделить корень в слове "песчаными"?
ПЕСЧаными или ПЕСчаными?

С одной стороны, слов "песчаными" образовано от слова "ПЕСок", значит корень должен быть "-пес-", но с другой стороны, многоие сайты пишут, что корень слова "-песч-".
Например, https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Какой вариант правильнее?

Заранее большое спасибо за ответ! :)

Comment: Справедливо пишут, ибо *Песчаник*.

Comment: В слове "песок"  к корню относится вся основа, там нет суффикса ОК. Песок — песч/ан/ый. О — беглая гласная, чередование К/Ч.  У этого слова сложная этимология, песок - непроизводное слово.  ОК — праславянский суффикс,  в славянских языках не выделяется.

Comment: значит корень "-песч-". Спасибо! :)